# How to account for a possible whitespace between matched words?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I would like to parse some personal calendar entries which may start with one or more tags. In an ideal world, I would have clean cases (below are three examples of three separate entries):

```
a description without tags
[one] [two] hello
[single] world
```

This should give me back, respectively:

- `a description without tags`
- `one`, `two`, `hello`
- `single`, `word`

The idea is to have as input: optionally a `[tag]` (or more separated by a space) and a description - ideally grouped into a list of tags (possibly empty), and a description string.

I think I have matched these cases with `(\[(\S+)\])*.+`. I am not sure, however, if the space between tags is correctly ignored.

Anyway, the reality is that my teenagers-sloppy-typing users will end up with entries such as

```
[glued1][glued2] wazaa
[glued10][glued20]glued decription
[glued]wazii
```

and similar ones.

**I would like to build a regex which would say *"from the beginning of the string, take what is between `[` and `]`, as many times as possible (possibly zero) and give me back these matches, and what follows the last `]` minus the possible space(s) between them"*.**

Isn't that too complex for a regex? The alternative is to parse the string character by character - which I will be able to do but this will be way less elegant.

Or - alternatively - how far can I go with the regex, and give up on the other cases (they will see that something is wrong when what they types is not parsed correctly anyway)

Comment: Is this case legit? `[tag1] [tag2] description [tag3]`

Comment: Can you show us the output you want for the given input....

Comment: I guess you need `r'\s*((?:\[[^][]*](?:\s*\[[^][]*])*)?)\s*(.*)'`, see 
 [**this Python demo**](https://ideone.com/hEiHW1)

Comment: @GRoutar: no, I would just go for tags at the start (or no tags) and the description afterwards

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse - I updated my question, is this better?

Comment: Could you just do a `.replace(']', ',').replace('[', '')` and replace more than 1 space with a single space via regex? Or can you add a more complicated example?

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple, you can just match all the contents inside square brackets with a simple regex `r"\[(.*?)\]"`. We'll test it over the given examples:

```
test_str = ['[glued1][glued2] wazaa','[glued10][glued20]glued decription','[glued]wazii','a description without tags','[one] [two] hello','[single] world']
```

Step by step:

```
import re
regex = r"\[(.*?)\]"
for s in test_str:
    print(f"{s} -> {re.findall(regex, s)}")
        print(re.findall(regex, s))
```

Which results in:

```
'[glued1][glued2] wazaa' -> ['glued1', 'glued2']
'[glued10][glued20]glued decription' -> ['glued10', 'glued20']
'[glued]wazii' -> ['glued']
'a description without tags' -> []
'[one] [two] hello' -> ['one', 'two']
'[single] world' -> ['single']
```

**PROBLEM!** This doesn't work if you use the square brackets somewhere inside the description.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your string won't contain any bracket besides the tags', you can try using a regex that matches everything but the brackets themselves (and whitespaces):

```
[^ \[\]]*
```

https://regex101.com/r/pUXAVC/1

Edit: This solution would split the descriptions' tokens into single groups. If you want them grouped together you can simply remove the whitespace character from the regex, `[^\[\]]*` and trim the extra whitespaces you get in your groups.

Answer (score 0):

I think you almost have it. Will this give you what you want?

```
^(\[\S+\]\s*)*\s*(.+)
```

`^` denotes the start of a string. `\s` denotes whitespace. So this says: at the start of the string, look for what is in the parentheses 0 or more times. Then look for 0 or more whitespace, then match what comes after. The only problem with this is that it captures the whitespace that may or may not come in between the tags. To solve this, perhaps you could have a post-processing step to strip the whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine as for my understanding of your needs:

```
(^[\[]+\]|[\w\s]+)+
```

https://regex101.com/r/0cA95I/1

Answer (score -1):

> Isn't that too complex for a regex?

Yes, at least for Python's, you'll have to do it in two steps:

- either match all the tags individually (using re.finditer) then takes whatever's left after the last match (that'll be your description)
- or match all the tags as a single group and the descrioption separately, then match your tags within the first group

You can put your regex in something like regex101 alongside your test cases and see easily enough that it doesn't quite work, and I don't think you can fix it up to actually do the entire thing with a single rege. Possibly in Perl. And even then it'd probably be less readable than doing two passes so not really worth it.